# I cannot get VPNC & NetworkManager running (IPSec Ubuntu 18.04 VPN to FritzBox) -

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, ipsec, vpnc

I cannot get VPNC working on Ubuntu 18.04 running on a Intel NUC.

I installed `network-manager-vpnc` and `network-manager-vpnc-gnome` and I entered all the credentials as required.  The connection starts to build up, but is dropped after a few seconds.

Can somebody point me in a suitable direction if I have to look further in Ubuntu for the solution"

Syslog says:

```
autonegotiation is unset or enabled, the speed and duplex are not writable
```

and then, four lines later:

```
no ifupdown configuration found")
```

Or, does the error lie in the VPN Setup/Connection?

What should I check and/or try?

Syslog:

```
Blockquote
10月 20 21:39:10 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info> [1540042750.9476] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
10月 20 21:39:10 madin-NUC7CJYH dhclient[1064]: bound to 192.168.21.128 -- renewal in 2147483648 seconds.
10月 20 21:39:10 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042750.9535] policy: set 'Wired connection 1' (eno1) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
10月 20 21:39:10 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042750.9548] device (eno1): Activation: successful, device activated.
10月 20 21:39:10 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042750.9566] manager: startup complete
10月 20 21:39:14 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042754.0001] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
10月 20 21:39:30 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042770.9807] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc" name="VPN 1" pid=1235 uid=1000 result="succe
10月 20 21:39:30 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042770.9927] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: Started the VPN service, PID 1864
10月 20 21:39:31 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042771.0148] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: Saw the service appear; activating connec
10月 20 21:39:31 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042771.0269] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: starting (3)
10月 20 21:39:31 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042771.0276] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: VPN connection: (ConnectInteractive) repl
10月 20 21:39:31 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042771.3114] manager: (tun0): new Tun device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
10月 20 21:39:31 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042771.3301] devices added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
10月 20 21:39:31 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042771.3307] device added (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0): no ifupdown configuration found.
10月 20 21:39:32 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: /usr/sbin/vpnc: authentication unsuccessful
10月 20 21:39:32 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <warn>  [1540042772.5197] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: failed: login-failed (0)
10月 20 21:39:32 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <warn>  [1540042772.5201] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: failed: connect-failed (1)
10月 20 21:39:32 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042772.5213] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopping (5)
10月 20 21:39:32 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042772.5216] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: VPN plugin: state changed: stopped (6)
10月 20 21:39:32 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042772.5271] vpn-connection[0x55bba549c220,efb1116f-9a2a-45a0-8d68-e94814c44bfc,"VPN 1",0]: VPN service disappeared
10月 20 21:39:32 madin-NUC7CJYH NetworkManager[733]: <info>  [1540042772.5302] devices removed (path: /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0, iface: tun0)
```

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 does not use `ifupdown` anymore. Maybe that could be the problem?!

Comment: I reset the entire system incl. the router, it is working now.  It may have been a problem with the credentials.

The question is resolved and can therefore be closed.